# Stepping through Solidity source code with deployed transaction from blockchain

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

Let's say I have deployed a contract in the blockchain. I have send in a transaction into that contract and it apparently went to through and got accepted to blockchain.

If I have the contract source code (Solidity) is it possible to take an existing transaction data (from etherscan.io or similar service) and step through it against the source code line-by-line to see how the transaction modified the contract state. Preferably also get the contract state from the blockchain how was it before the transaction was run.

This is akin to old fashioned symbol debugging with more traditional compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what [REMIX](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/master/README.md) is trying to do but it's still in Alpha